# Can I use azure logic App to remove old azure table row?

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an azure table that contains fair amount of log info. Now I am looking at ways to delete old records (say X days ago).

Azure logic app provides Recurrence function and has built-in routine to delete Entity in Azure Table. Sounds really great, However, I got stuck really quick. This delete entity function requires Partition key and Row key. However, as I want to delete rows base on TimeStamp field, seems I can't use this one.
[image]

Ok, I tried to retrieve the old entries first and loop through each row and then delete them one by one. (copy paste this [tutorial](https://sameeraman.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/logic-apps-delete-files-older-than-x-days-from-a-blob-storage/))

So I tris to create a filter query to retrieve old entries first:

```
@less(item()?['TimeStamp'].addDays(utcNow(), -7))
```

However, azure says my expression is not valid. So I guess above expression is for blob, and not for azure tables??

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: If you have a large amount of data to delete (millions of lines), logic app may not be the best option in term of cost as you pay per executed action/connector. It may not be relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the logic apps, `Get entities` action support add `Filter Query`, so add it and use the query expression like this `Timestamp ge datetime'2019-05-20T01:32Z'`. Then delete the entities you get.

[image]

[image]

Here is the description about [Timestamp Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#timestamp-property), the below is my result page.

[image]

**Update:**
Yo could use expression `addDays(utcNow(),-41)` to filter the data, however you need to add `''` or it won't be recognized.

[image]

This is the filter result.

[image]

Comment: hi, can I change the hard coded datetime on the fly? something like utcNow()-7 days?

Comment: @daxu, yes it supports, I update the answer. If this could help you, you could mark it as the answer.